# Solve recurrence with characteristic polynomial $a_n=7\cdot a_{n-1} -7\cdot a_{n-2}+175\cdot a_{n-3}+450\cdot a_{n-4}+(5+13\cdot n)\cdot9^n $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The equation
$$a_n=7\cdot a_{n-1} -7\cdot a_{n-2}+175\cdot a_{n-3}+450\cdot a_{n-4}+(5+13\cdot n)\cdot9^n \enspace,$$
where
$a_0=148, a_1=144, a_2=-55, a_3=-61$.

I assume that a solution will look like $a^s_n+a^h_n$ , where $a^s_n$. I solve like 
$$x^4-7x^3+7x^2-175x-450=0 \enspace,$$
then get $x_1=-2,\ \ x_2=9,\ \ x_3=-5i,\ \ x_4=5i\ \ $
and don't know what next.

But the real problem is with the second part $(5+13\cdot n)\cdot9^n$. I completely don't know what do with that.

Comment: What is $a_n^s$ $a_n^h$? The solution should look like $\sum_{j=1}^4 c_jx_j^n$.

Comment: @JulianMejia I thought it will be nonhomogeneous and it will look like that, but I'm not sure about that... $\sum_{i=1}^r=c_ia_{n-1}+F(n)$

Comment: Oh, I haven't read carefully, yes, it's not homogeneous.

Comment: since $9$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial, any constant $C$ with $C 9^n$ still gives zero ate the end. Next, we add in $Dn 9^n$ and see if things can be adjusted. I would expect that to be enough. If not, you try $(E n^2 + Dn+C) 9^n$

Answer (score 1):

Considering the homogeneous

$$
a_n-7\cdot a_{n-1}+7\cdot a_{n-2}-175\cdot a_{n-3}-450\cdot a_{n-4}=0
$$

after substituting $a_n = C_0 \beta^n$ we obtain

$$
C_0(\beta -9) (\beta +2) \left(\beta ^2+25\right) \beta ^{n-4}=0
$$

so we have the set of exponent solutions (for $n > 4$ assuming $\beta\ne 0$)

$$
\{-2,9,\pm i 5\}
$$

then

$$
a_n^h = C_1(-2)^n+C_29^n+C_3 (i 5)^n+C_4 (-i 5)^n
$$

for the particular we adopt

$$
a_n^p = (c_1+c_2n+c_3n^2)9^n
$$

and after substitution we obtain

$$
a_n^h = 9^n \left(c_1+\frac{16996635 n}{1359556}+\frac{9477 n^2}{2332}\right)
$$

and finally

$$
a_n =  C_1(-2)^n+C_29^n+C_3 (i 5)^n+C_4 (-i 5)^n + 9^n \left(c_1+\frac{16996635 n}{1359556}+\frac{9477 n^2}{2332}\right)
$$

Comment: I'm so glad of your help, but can you say how did you get those numbers after second substitution ?

Comment: @DrFreeman Substituting $a_n^h = (c_1+c_2n+c_3n^2)9^n$ into $a_n-7\cdot a_{n-1}+7\cdot a_{n-2}-175\cdot a_{n-3}-450\cdot a_{n-4}=(5+13n)9^n$ After that the result should be $0$ so we compute the values for $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that this fact is accomplished.